# Errors importing stats module from SciPy

Tags: numpy, scipy

I'm trying to use some of the functions available here

http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.stats.stats.html

but I can only seem to get access to some of them.  For instance after I do `from scipy import stats` I can do something like stats.gmean([3,4]) to get the geometric mean, but when I try stats.samplestd([3,4]) I get an error that says the module has no attribute samplestd.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm running enthought's python distribution if that helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.stats.samplestd()` was [deprecated in SciPy 0.8](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.8.x/reference/generated/scipy.stats.samplestd.html#scipy.stats.samplestd) and removed in SciPy 0.9.  Probably, you are using version 0.9.  You should use [`numpy.std()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html#numpy.std) instead.

Be sure to use the SciPy docs matching the version you use.

Comment: Thanks, is there a function for sample standard dev or do I need to do the conversion from population to sample myself?

Comment: @tshauck: `numpy.std()` returns the same value the deprecated `samplestd()` would have returned.  No need for any conversions.

Comment: numpy.var, numpy.std and similar have a ddof argument if you want to adjust the denominator, e.g to get the unbiased estimator for the variance you can set ddof=1, so the denominatory is (n_observations - 1)